# How to remove function name from Javascript object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map and I want to edit a polygon. I successfully do this, but when I finish the editing, the coordinates are saved like:

```
,,LatLng(44.94633, 26.00773),LatLng(44.93588, 25.94318),LatLng(44.94245, 25.90645),LatLng(44.91814, 25.87074),LatLng(44.91328, 25.9346),LatLng(44.90015, 25.97031),LatLng(44.90112, 26.11519)"
```

I only want to have the coordinates without function name. How can I do this? Thanks!

```
map.on("dragend", function(e){
  poligon = polygon.getLatLngs();
  poligon1 = poligon.toString();
  $('#geo').val(poligon1);
  console.log(poligon1);
});
```

[image]

Comment: You may need to access the coordinates directly `poligon.lat; poligon.lng;`?

Comment: I don't think so... I don't have separate field for latitude and longitude, and only have 1 field where I add both

Comment: I think as per http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#polyline-getlatlngs , `getLatLngs()` will returns an array of the points, you have run for loop and find each LatLngs...

Comment: I already have it:  var zona = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>');
       for(var i=0; i < zona.length; i++) {

Comment: What exactly you want to write in that Textbox (Geolocatii) ??

Comment: Only the coordinates: ,,44.94633, 26.00773, 44.93588, 25.94318" , without () and function name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by writing one line:

```
 poligon = polygon.getLatLngs();
      //this is what I added
      poligon2=poligon.join(',').match(/([\d\.]+)/g).join(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `toString()` u will get an `array` of `objects`

```
var arr=[];
console.log(polygon.getLatLngs());
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    arr=polygon.getLatLngs();
    console.log(arr[i].lat);
    console.log(arr[i].lng);
    console.log("("+arr[i].lat +","+arr[i].lng+")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override toString method of LatLng prototype at your project init

```
L.LatLng.prototype.toString = function() {
  return '(' + this.lat + ',' + this.lng + ')'; 
}
```

Then you'll see output like this cause Array.toString() recursively call toString() on every element in collection.

> (44.94633, 26.00773),(44.94633, 26.00773)

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add an answer.

This should work in general: give it a string, it will try to find all numbers, and return them in an array.

```
<script>
var mystring = "LatLng(44.94633, 26.00773),LatLng(44.93588, 25.94318),LatLng(44.94245, 25.90645),LatLng(44.91814, 25.87074),LatLng(44.91328, 25.9346),LatLng(44.90015, 25.97031),LatLng(44.90112, 26.11519)";

function isNumeric(input) {
 return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
}

// reads a string, finds numbers (float), returns the numbers in an array
function numbersInString(string) {
 var s = 0, temp=0, result = [];
 for(var i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
   s = string.substr(i,1);   // search 1 character, see if it's a number (digit)
   if(isNumeric(s)) {
     // parseFloat wil read as many characters as it can, and drop the rest
     temp = parseFloat(string.substr(i));
     // okay, now skip the length of the float
     i = i + temp.toString().length ;
     result.push(temp);  
   }
 }
 return result;
}

window.onload = function() {
   var numbers = numbersInString(mystring);
   document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += numbers.join(',');
}
</script>
<div id="log"></div>
```